# TypeScript is referencing non-static method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to load a module from the root, so I am using `require.main.require()` to do so. Since import cannot access the root, I need to use require. However, this is referencing the wrong `connect()` method:

```
export class MongoClient extends EventEmitter {
  connect(callback: MongoCallback<MongoClient>): void;
}
```

What I need is for it to reference the static method:

```
export class MongoClient extends EventEmitter {
  static connect(uri: string, options?: MongoClientOptions): Promise<MongoClient>;
}
```

The code runs fine when compiled and executed with node, it's just that it is showing an error in the editor. This is what I am doing:

```
declare type MongoClient = import('mongodb').MongoClient

const mongo = require.main && require.main.require('mongodb')
const MongoClient: MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient

async function connect() {
  let url = 'mongodb://....' 
  await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
}
```

> Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `Expected 0-1 arguments, but got 2.`

Comment: which line is that?

Comment: probably here? `connect(uri: string, options?: MongoClientOptions)`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yeah that is correct

Comment: SO it looks like it tried to call `connect(callback: MongoCallback<MongoClient>)` with one argument in it

Comment: must be here `await MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })`

Comment: Yeah this is because you have declared the variable to be of type MongoClient, so it thinks that MongoClient is an instance, not the class.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to declare it as newable `new()` though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the fix was to just use the `typeof` keyword along with a union type when declaring the `type`.

```
declare type MongoClient = typeof import('mongodb').MongoClient | import('mongodb').MongoClient
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that typescript is expecting a member function call as `connect` is being called on a variable, but the type declaration specifies `connect` as static.

Since you have to import through require.main which results in an instance as opposed to a static class, the easiest workaround is to re declare connect as an instance member.

```
import { MongoClient, MongoClientOptions} from "mongodb";

declare class MyMongoClient extends MongoClient {
  connect(uri: string, options?: MongoClientOptions): Promise<MongoClient>;
  connect(): Promise<MongoClient>;
}

const mongo = require.main && require.main.require('mongodb')
const mongoClient = mongo.MongoClient  as MyMongoClient

async function connect() {
  let url = 'mongodb://....'
  await mongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true })
}
```

Because of the declare keyword, the actual module will not be pulled in after transpilation.